# MVC 4 Bundle - unable to bundle content e.g. css/javascript outside MVC project content folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

For an MVC 4 project, I have a requirement to include/bundle content files that reside outside the MVC project e.g. somewhere in a CDN.

This works:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/Css/site.css"));
```

This does not work:

```
bundles.Add(newStyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("D:/Media/Styles/Css/site.css"));
```

The error I get is:

> The URL 'D:/Media/Styles/Css/site.css' is not valid. Only application
>   relative URLs (~/url) are allowed. Parameter name: virtualPaths

In short, is it at all possible to have asset files residing outside the project's Content folder, for example when using a CDN? if so, what is the best approach?

Answer (score 3):

You can only use relative paths and CDN. The resources can be outside the Content folder,  so you can have them in a different folder within your site.

[You can also use a CDN like this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification):

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{

    bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    //add link to jquery on the CDN
    var jqueryCdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",
                jqueryCdnPath).Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    // Code removed for clarity.
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble finding much documentation on this aside from the link you included.  Would this practice be the same for a new StyleBundle CDN?

Comment: Just achiueved this exact behavior, StyleBundles can be implemented in the same was from a CDN.