# Asp and IIS issues

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, iis

When I am trying to deploy an ASP App to IIS, I'm having some serious problems with the scripts and styles.

what i am doing is: first I'm publishing my app using visual studio and then on IIS I'm clicking on a website then deploy and then import an application

The site is working as expected and I am able to access it using the port and URL specified, but I'm losing my css, javascript and jQuery.

some facts:

1. I am setting debug to false in my Web.config :  `<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />`
2. I installed **Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization** from NuGet to my app
3. when using firebug or chrome canary to inspect whats happening I can see my links like the following:
   **href="/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" etc ...
   when I change it to 
   href=" Content/css/bootstrap.min.css"**

i.e just changing "/Content" to "Content" makes everything works as expected

any thoughts ? !

Comment: Is your application in the root of the website (e.g. `http://servername`), or in a subpath (`http://servername/MyApplication/`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [MVC 4 Bundle - unable to bundle content e.g. css/javascript outside MVC project content folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375735/mvc-4-bundle-unable-to-bundle-content-e-g-css-javascript-outside-mvc-project). You can add the bundle using a "CDN path", where you put the proper URL to the bundle:

```
string cdnPath = "http://yourserver/yourpath/Content/foo.js";
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", cdnPath).Include(
```

Or take the advice from [MVC Bundling and CSS relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484188/mvc-bundling-and-css-relative-urls):

> Don't use bundling on CSS with paths because it is broken except in very simple cases. It's much easier to just directly link minified CSS.